# Does direct query connect to sql server using gateway credential or report viewer credentials?

Tags: powerbi

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-about#security

The article mentions

> DirectQuery allows for a report viewer's credentials to be passed
> through to the underlying source and security rules to be applied
> there. Single sign-on is supported to SQL Azure datasources, and
> through the data gateway to on-premises SQL servers.

This implies that report viewers credential is used to query underlying data.

Where as further down it contradicts this:

> As discussed earlier in this article, a report in DirectQuery always
> uses the same fixed credentials to connect to the underlying data
> source, after it's published to the Power BI service. This behavior
> applies to DirectQuery, not to live connections to SQL Server Analysis
> Services, which is different in this respect. Immediately after
> publish of a DirectQuery report, it's necessary to configure the
> credentials of the user that will be used. Until you configure the
> credentials, opening the report on the Power BI service would result
> in an error.
>
> Once the user credentials are provided, then those credentials will be
> used whichever user who opens the report. In this way, it's exactly
> like imported data. Every user sees the same data, unless row-level
> security has been defined as part of the report.

Does direct query connect to sql server using gateway credential or report viewer credentials?

Answer (score 0):

That doc is out-of-date.  Single-Sign On (SSO) is available as an option for many cloud and [on-prem data sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-sso-overview), including SQL Server and SSO is required for DirectQuery to Power BI Datasets.

> All connections to remote Power BI Datasets models are made using
> single sign-on.

[Using DirectQuery for Power BI datasets and Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-datasets-azure-analysis-services)

Comment: Does direct query connect to sql server using gateway credential or report viewer credentials?

Comment: Depends on whether you set SSO for the gateway connection.